# Can Firebase Dynamic links be used for App install Ad Campaigns?

Tags: firebase, ads, facebook-marketing-api, google-advertising-id

I've looked at use cases for Firebase links and it seems that non paid campaigns through email and whatnot are an example.

I wanted to see if anyone had any experience with running Facebook, Twitter, Google, any paid platform ads with Firebase links that take them to the app store based on what OS they are using.

The link would be for an app on the app store. Not sure if this is a good way to do it or sticking with a landing page and utm links. The goal is to track conversions and send them to the correct app store depending on device without the use of a landing page.

Answer (score 0):

No, you cannot use Firebase to track installs from Facebook ads. Because Facebook requires you to use the link for the actual app store page (or Google play page), and not a redirect link (which is what Firebase calls Dynamic Links Firebase Dynamic Links  |  Firebase). You can track ads in AdWords through Firebase, but not other platforms that don’t let you put in a redirect link.